# VB6 Common Dialog

Tags: vb6

```
Public Function Open_File(FileNames() As String)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
With CommonDialog
    .Filter = "Bitmap Image File (*.BMP)|*.BMP|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    .DefaultExt = ".BMP"
    .DialogTitle = "Open"
    .MaxFileSize = 32767
    .Flags = cdlOFNAllowMultiselect + cdlOFNLongNames + cdlOFNExplorer
    .ShowOpen
    If .FileName = "" Then GoTo ErrorHandler
    FileNames() = Split(.FileName, vbNullChar)
End With
If UBound(FileNames) = 0 Then
    temp = FileNames(0)
    ReDim FileNames(1)
    FileNames(1) = temp
End If
Open_File = True
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Open_File = False
End Function
```

So with this code, if I call this to specify a few files, it works perfectly; however, when I put more than a few files, it exceeds the MaxFileSize limit. Is there a way to get the many files with the CommonDialog mechanism or would you recommend something else entirely?

Comment: I tested your code with a set of 300 filenames, sized to 36/35 characters length and it works. Can you provide a set of "a few files" which exceeds the `MaxFileSize` limit? It don't understand how you could exceed the limit. By the way you should code with `Option Explicit On` and avoid using GoTo, especially to deal an error case with a empty filename set.

Comment: Do you mean when there are a lot of files in the folder?

Comment: The vb6 common dialog control property MaxFileSize is an integer (short integer). Max value of 32,767. You can't change that. You can investigate using the winapi common dialog interfaces, that might provide you with the functionality you request.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your responses. @Amessihel, sorry if I worded my post a 
little confusingly; so take if you put 300 (a few) files into the structure, it 
will work perfectly but in my case, I want it to handle thousands (many files) sized to 36/35 characters length.

Comment: @MarkL, could you point me to a place where I could find some more information on the APIs that you mentioned above?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? In my opinion you shouldn't use a common dialog if you got a very huge amount of files. Better let the user choose a directory and process in a loop the whole content (or the file whose name matches a given pattern).

Comment: I got it, Thanks!